# How to loop through complex JSON in Python 3.x

Tags: python, json

Currently, I'm building a dashboard for my home where I get temperature values from the Honeywell API. I'm trying to loop through a complex JSON that I got from the API to get all the device current temperatures.

Since I'm quite new to Python I have no clue how to get this sorted. Here is an example response:

```
[
    {
        "locationID": 5018081,
        "type": "Residential",
        "hasStation": true,
        "devices": [
            {
                "gatewayId": 4773548,
                "deviceID": 6575395,
                "thermostatModelType": "EMEA_ZONE",
                "deviceType": 128,
                "name": "Badkamer 1e",
                "scheduleCapable": false,
                "holdUntilCapable": false,
                "thermostat": {
                    "units": "Celsius",
                    "indoorTemperature": 18.8300,
                    "outdoorTemperature": 128.0000,
                    "outdoorTemperatureAvailable": false,
                    "outdoorHumidity": 128.0000,
                    "outdootHumidityAvailable": false,
                    "indoorHumidity": 128.0000,
                    "indoorTemperatureStatus": "Measured",
                    "indoorHumidityStatus": "NotAvailable",
                    "outdoorTemperatureStatus": "NotAvailable",
                    "outdoorHumidityStatus": "NotAvailable",
                    "isCommercial": false,
                    "allowedModes": [
                        "Heat",
                        "Off"
                    ],
                    "deadband": 0.0000,
                    "minHeatSetpoint": 5.0000,
                    "maxHeatSetpoint": 35.0000,
                    "minCoolSetpoint": 50.0000,
                    "maxCoolSetpoint": 90.0000,
                    "changeableValues": {
                        "mode": "Off",
                        "heatSetpoint": {
                            "value": 19.0,
                            "status": "Scheduled"
                        },
                        "vacationHoldDays": 0
                    },
                    "scheduleCapable": false,
                    "vacationHoldChangeable": false,
                    "vacationHoldCancelable": false,
                    "scheduleHeatSp": 0.0000,
                    "scheduleCoolSp": 0.0000
                },
                "alertSettings": {
                    "deviceID": 6575395,
                    "tempHigherThanActive": true,
                    "tempHigherThan": 30.0000,
                    "tempHigherThanMinutes": 0,
                    "tempLowerThanActive": true,
                    "tempLowerThan": 5.0000,
                    "tempLowerThanMinutes": 0,
                    "faultConditionExistsActive": false,
                    "faultConditionExistsHours": 0,
                    "normalConditionsActive": true,
                    "communicationLostActive": false,
                    "communicationLostHours": 0,
                    "communicationFailureActive": true,
                    "communicationFailureMinutes": 15,
                    "deviceLostActive": false,
                    "deviceLostHours": 0
                },
                "isUpgrading": false,
                "isAlive": true,
                "thermostatVersion": "02.00.17.00",
                "macID": "B82CA0CCEB90",
                "locationID": 5018081,
                "domainID": 60304,
                "instance": 9
            },
            {
                "gatewayId": 4773548,
                "deviceID": 6575388,
                "thermostatModelType": "EMEA_ZONE",
                "deviceType": 128,
                "name": "Badkamer BG",
                "scheduleCapable": false,
                "holdUntilCapable": false,
                "thermostat": {
                    "units": "Celsius",
                    "indoorTemperature": 20.3200,
                    "outdoorTemperature": 128.0000,
                    "outdoorTemperatureAvailable": false,
                    "outdoorHumidity": 128.0000,
                    "outdootHumidityAvailable": false,
                    "indoorHumidity": 128.0000,
                    "indoorTemperatureStatus": "Measured",
                    "indoorHumidityStatus": "NotAvailable",
                    "outdoorTemperatureStatus": "NotAvailable",
                    "outdoorHumidityStatus": "NotAvailable",
                    "isCommercial": false,
                    "allowedModes": [
                        "Heat",
                        "Off"
                    ],
                    "deadband": 0.0000,
                    "minHeatSetpoint": 5.0000,
                    "maxHeatSetpoint": 35.0000,
                    "minCoolSetpoint": 50.0000,
                    "maxCoolSetpoint": 90.0000,
                    "changeableValues": {
                        "mode": "Off",
                        "heatSetpoint": {
                            "value": 19.0,
                            "status": "Scheduled"
                        },
                        "vacationHoldDays": 0
                    },
                    "scheduleCapable": false,
                    "vacationHoldChangeable": false,
                    "vacationHoldCancelable": false,
                    "scheduleHeatSp": 0.0000,
                    "scheduleCoolSp": 0.0000
                },
                "alertSettings": {
                    "deviceID": 6575388,
                    "tempHigherThanActive": true,
                    "tempHigherThan": 30.0000,
                    "tempHigherThanMinutes": 0,
                    "tempLowerThanActive": true,
                    "tempLowerThan": 5.0000,
                    "tempLowerThanMinutes": 0,
                    "faultConditionExistsActive": false,
                    "faultConditionExistsHours": 0,
                    "normalConditionsActive": true,
                    "communicationLostActive": false,
                    "communicationLostHours": 0,
                    "communicationFailureActive": true,
                    "communicationFailureMinutes": 15,
                    "deviceLostActive": false,
                    "deviceLostHours": 0
                },
                "isUpgrading": false,
                "isAlive": true,
                "thermostatVersion": "02.00.17.00",
                "macID": "B82CA0CCEB90",
                "locationID": 5018081,
                "domainID": 60304,
                "instance": 2
            },
            {
                "gatewayId": 4773548,
                "deviceID": 6575389,
                "thermostatModelType": "EMEA_ZONE",
                "deviceType": 128,
                "name": "Garage",
                "scheduleCapable": false,
                "holdUntilCapable": false,
                "thermostat": {
                    "units": "Celsius",
                    "indoorTemperature": 17.1600,
                    "outdoorTemperature": 128.0000,
                    "outdoorTemperatureAvailable": false,
                    "outdoorHumidity": 128.0000,
                    "outdootHumidityAvailable": false,
                    "indoorHumidity": 128.0000,
                    "indoorTemperatureStatus": "Measured",
                    "indoorHumidityStatus": "NotAvailable",
                    "outdoorTemperatureStatus": "NotAvailable",
                    "outdoorHumidityStatus": "NotAvailable",
                    "isCommercial": false,
                    "allowedModes": [
                        "Heat",
                        "Off"
                    ],
                    "deadband": 0.0000,
                    "minHeatSetpoint": 5.0000,
                    "maxHeatSetpoint": 35.0000,
                    "minCoolSetpoint": 50.0000,
                    "maxCoolSetpoint": 90.0000,
                    "changeableValues": {
                        "mode": "Off",
                        "heatSetpoint": {
                            "value": 17.0,
                            "status": "Scheduled"
                        },
                        "vacationHoldDays": 0
                    },
                    "scheduleCapable": false,
                    "vacationHoldChangeable": false,
                    "vacationHoldCancelable": false,
                    "scheduleHeatSp": 0.0000,
                    "scheduleCoolSp": 0.0000
                },
                "alertSettings": {
                    "deviceID": 6575389,
                    "tempHigherThanActive": true,
                    "tempHigherThan": 30.0000,
                    "tempHigherThanMinutes": 0,
                    "tempLowerThanActive": true,
                    "tempLowerThan": 5.0000,
                    "tempLowerThanMinutes": 0,
                    "faultConditionExistsActive": false,
                    "faultConditionExistsHours": 0,
                    "normalConditionsActive": true,
                    "communicationLostActive": false,
                    "communicationLostHours": 0,
                    "communicationFailureActive": true,
                    "communicationFailureMinutes": 15,
                    "deviceLostActive": false,
                    "deviceLostHours": 0
                },
                "isUpgrading": false,
                "isAlive": true,
                "thermostatVersion": "02.00.17.00",
                "macID": "B82CA0CCEB90",
                "locationID": 5018081,
                "domainID": 60304,
                "instance": 3
            }
        ],
        "oneTouchButtons": [],
        "weather": {
            "condition": "Cloudy",
            "temperature": 8.7,
            "units": "Celsius",
            "humidity": 91,
            "phrase": "Cloudy"
        },
        "daylightSavingTimeEnabled": true,
        "timeZone": {
            "id": "W. Europe Standard Time",
            "displayName": "(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna",
            "offsetMinutes": 60,
            "currentOffsetMinutes": 60,
            "usingDaylightSavingTime": true
        },
        "oneTouchActionsSuspended": false,
        "isLocationOwner": true,
        "locationOwnerID": 4172939,
        "canSearchForContractors": true
    }
]
```

Does anyone here know how to get per device in the devices array the `thermostat.indoortemperature` and the `thermostat.changeableValues.HeatSetpoint.Value`?

Comment: This isn't complicated JSON. I suggest you open it in your web browser and it  might be easier to navigate. It appears to be a list with elements that are dictionaries. Then inside of those dictionaries is another dictionary with the key thermostat. You can work through it methodically and figure it out.

Comment: Okay check, complex might've been a bit exaggerating. It's not the complexity that is bothering me, more which method to use in Python to loop through the dictionaries and get the values.

Comment: The same way that you would do it if the data *didn't* come from JSON. Take it one step at a time. For example, the response (after parsing the JSON) is a list, yeah? With just the one element? Do you know how to write the code to get that element? Then, that element is a dict with a `devices` key, right? Can you get the list stored under that key? Now, you want to iterate over the elements of that list, right? Do you know how to write a loop that iterates over a list? Take it a step at a time and reason through it. Ask a specific question when you encounter a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got a list containing one big dictionary. That dictionary has a `devices` key-value pair, where the value is a list of dictionaries, one for each device. If `data` is your JSON structure, you can iterate through the device-dictionaries in the following way:

```
data = ...

for device in data[0]["devices"]:
    indoor_temp = device["thermostat"]["indoorTemperature"]
    heat_set_point = device["changeableValues"]["heatSetpoint"]["value"]
    print("Device ID: {}".format(device["deviceID"]))
    print("Indoor temperature: {}".format(indoor_temp))
    print("Heat set point: {}\n".format(heat_set_point))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a json array.. convert it to array of dictionaries then loop through it and get the values from each dictionary using its corresponding key.

```
import json

json_array_string = u'[{ "key":"value", ... }, {...}, ... ]'
array = json.loads(json_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments this is a list with elements that are dictionaries.

Save the list, I saved as `a` (make sure true/false are True/False)

The list has a length of one, for each location.

Choose the first element of the list

```
a[0]
```

The list contains a dictionary, so open the dictionary for the value you want `devices`.  Navigating the elements is like navigating file structure on your compute

```
a[0]['devices']
```

This gives you a list with three dictionaries

Iterate through the dictionaries.  Reference the `thermostat` sub-dictionary and choose the `indoorTemperature` key

```
[i['thermostat']['indoorTemperature'] for i in a[0]['devices']]
```

This gives you the `indoorTemperature' for each device

I dont know exactly what output you want, but you can use this logic to get what you need!

In general to get value of a list indicate the index (eg `a[0]`) to get the value of a dictionary indicate the key (eg device['thermostat'])

Comment: Similar to Pauls answer, this works for me, thanks a lot for answering this probably simple question, it got me stuck haha.